# cypress run fails from CI pipeline with version cypress 7.7.0

Tags: cypress

I am trying to update cypress package in my test project to `7.7.0` and the tests run fine locally with `cypress run`.

The same command when running in an Azure pipeline with `ubuntu-20.04`, fails to start the test with the below.

```
     at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:218:26)
     at Object.watch (fs.js:1525:34)
     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:116:15)
     at setFsWatchListener (/home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:163:15)
     at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:325:14)
     at NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:548:19)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
     at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:597:16)
     at /home/vsts/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:435:21
     at Function.all (<anonymous>:null:null)
  {
  errno: -28,
   syscall: 'watch',
   code: 'ENOSPC',
   path: 'e2e/integration',
   filename: 'e2e/integration'
 }
```

is this a known issue with the new version of cypress?

Comment: No thats not normal. Do you have a second process running?

You can also try raising the inotify limit cause this seems to be the cause:

In Ubuntu it should be:  
  
`sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`